# How to get "public static final int" value by name?

Tags: java, android

I created a class to extend KeyEvent:

```
public class myKeyEvent extends KeyEvent {
    public static final int MY_KEYCODE_01 = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A;
    //...
    public static final int MY_KEYCODE_30 = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Z;
}
```

Now, i want to get the Integer value by the variable name (eg. "MY_KEYCODE_01" should return integer value KeyEvent.KeyCODE_A) from another class (another file).

I tried to:

```
try{
    Class cls = myKeyEvent.class.getClass();
    Field field = cls.getDeclaredField("MY_KEYCODE_01");
    int value = (Integer) field.get(cls);
    Log.v("TAG", "Field value is " + value);

} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    Log.e("TAG", "Field either doesn't exist or is not public: " + e.toString() );
}
```

In LogCat:

```
Field either doesn't exist or is not public: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: MY_KEYCODE_01
```

How can I do it?

Comment: If the `myKeyEvent` class is `public`, then I guess you can simply do it like this: `Field field = KeyEvent.MY_KEYCODE_01;` because the `MY_KEYCODE_01` field is also `public`

Comment: Renaming things that way is going to be confusing - those numbers aren't particularily helpful to developers (especially since you seem to have skipped a few).  Also, static fields are inherited, so you should be able to access them as `myKeyEvent.KEYCODE_A` (please name that class a little better).  What exactly are you trying to accomplish (besides the reflection, which is a bit pointless, because you've hardwired which class is being used...)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class is `myKeyEvent.class` if you do `myKeyEvent.class.getClass()` you are getting the class of the class object which is `Class`.  Drop the getClass()

You should be able to see the class is not correct in a debugger.

Comment: This moddification was made and still the same error: `Field either doesn't exist or is not public: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: MY_KEYCODE_01`

Comment: Can you try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myKeyEvent.class.getDeclaredFields()));`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the possible code:

```
 int value=0;
    try {
        Class  aClass = MyKeyEvent.class;

        Field f = aClass.getDeclaredField("MY_KEYCODE_01");
        Log.d(TAG, f.toString());
        value = f.getInt(null);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "value = " + value);
```

I've decided also add explanation. In the line `Class  aClass = MyKeyEvent.class;` we create an instance of Class that represents our MyKeyEvent class. After that we get declared field with the specified name. The most difficult part is `value = f.getInt(null);`. Here we get the value of field f. But in the general case this value is different for every object of MyKeyEvent class. So as MY_KEYCODE_01 declared as static final it has the same value for all objects. Thus, as a parameter for  `getInt` function we use null.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you need it for? You are able to do this using reflection in Java, but I'm pretty sure you don't want and don't really need to do this. Accessing a variable by a String with its name is not a regular way of getting the variable's value and may cause a lot of problems in further development.

Maybe try to adapt a Dictionary or an enum type instead?

Answer (score 0):

The varriable `MY_KEYCODE_01` and `MY_KEYCODE_30` are declared as static. So you don't need to use `getClass`. just use `myKeyEvent.MY_KEYCODE_01` or `myKeyEvent.MY_KEYCODE_30` and print it in Logcat. Some thing like this:

```
Log.i("TAG", "Field value is " + myKeyEvent.MY_KEYCODE_01);
```

Hope You will get the desired value.